# The ring of formal series in a variable $R=k[[x]]$ is a local ring, where the ideal maximal $m$ is the ideal of all series with term independent zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

**The ring of formal series in a variable $R=k[[x]]$ is a local ring, where the ideal maximal $m$ is the ideal of all series with term independent zero**

I have already noticed this [Maximal ideals of the ring of formal polynomials over a ring $R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674109/maximal-ideals-of-the-ring-of-formal-polynomials-over-a-ring-r)  and I know that $k[[x]]$ is a local ring because $k$ field is a local ring, what I do not know is how to prove that the maximal ideal of $k[[x]]$ has that shape ($m$ is the ideal of all series with term independent zero.)

Comment: All you have to do it to prove an element is invertible iff it's not in $xk[[x]]$.

Comment: Agree with the above comment, but I don't understand ``I know that $k[[x]]$ is a local ring because k field is a local ring." If you know it's local, I'd think you'd know its maximal ideal. I suspect that you need to think harder about what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x)=xk[[x]]$ is a proper ideal consisting of elements with constant term $0$ (you agree, yes?)

$k[[x]]/(x)\cong k$  (you agree, yes?)

That last thing means $(x)$ is maximal. Since you already say you know the ring is local, then $(x)$ is the unique maximal ideal.